# Refer to a Java attribute from a XML file

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to know if it was possible to refer to a Java attribute from a XML configuration file.

To be more precise, that's what my XML file looks like now :

```
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
<property name="jobDetail">
    <ref local="exampleJob" />
</property>

<!-- run monday at 10 --><!-- 0 0 10 ? * MON -->
<property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 10 ? * MON"/>
</bean>
```

And that's what I'd like to get (it's not working) :

```
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
<property name="jobDetail">
    <ref local="exampleJob" />
</property>

<!-- run monday at 10 --><!-- 0 0 10 ? * MON -->
<property name="cronExpression">
    <value>fr.bla.web.utils.APP_VAR.attribut</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

where APP_VAR is a Java interface and attribut a final static attribute I am interested in.

Is it possible ?

Comment: What app is processing this XML? Something to do with Java beans apparently? If so please make that explicit. You can certainly put that value in an XML file, but the question is about whether some application can retrieve the referenced attribute, right?

Comment: Well, I didn't know whether working with beans was relevant, so I didn't mention it. In fact, I don't want to put the value in the XML file, I want that value to be set in the APP_VAR interface, which contains most of the app's variables, like folder pathes, etc.

Comment: When I said "you can certainly put that value in an XML file", I meant you can put `<value>fr.bla.web.utils.APP_VAR.attribut</value>` in an XML file. The question is whether an app that consumes the XML will be able to use that to extract a value from the APP_VAR interface. In theory, of course it's possible, but that doesn't help you much. If we knew more about the app that will consume the XML, e.g. what frameworks it uses, we could try to answer in practical terms whether and how it could dereference `fr.bla.web.utils.APP_VAR.attribut`.

Comment: Dudes! Wheel has been invented long time ago! It's called XPath!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is doable using this:

```
<property name="cronExpression">
    <util:constant static-field="fr.bla.web.utils.APP_VAR.attribut"/>
</property>
```

but to be able to use the util:constant you have to add the **util** namespace into your beans element:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
```

note: you can also use "spring-util-2.5.xsd" (for spring 2.5) or the generic "spring-util.xsd" (without the suffix "-3.0" that I have used). it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

XML by itself is just a textual representation for data and so, is independent of platform or language. However, depending on what you're using to either generate/consume the XML, you might be able to substitute/lookup the value that you want.

More details about your environment and what you're going to use to create/read the XML will help you get a more specific answer.

Comment: Well, it's a GWT webapp, and the XML file is an application-context.xml file. I think it was generated manually, and is updated whenever a new Dao or a new Service is created.

Answer (score 0):

XPath:

```
/fr/bla/web/utils/APP_VAR[@attribute]
```

Learn it. You won't regret.

Example of use:

```
    // XPath expression
    String xp = "/Envelope/Body/*[position()=1]";

    // opening source XML
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(testMessage));           

    // parsing XML to DOM
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(false); 
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(is);       

    // compiling XPath (to re-use)  
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpathCompiled = factory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpathCompiled.compile(xp);

    // getting nodes/values matching the XPath from the XML
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: Well, although it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, it was worth trying and interesting. Thank you ! Now I know how to edit a xml file with java and XPath